# Regex taking whole line instead of exact words

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to match a list of different items in a text. I created a regex but it matches the whole string instead of each seperate item.

This is my current regex:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]\](.*)\. {1}
```

My test text:

```
[step 1] test blahblah blah [A] test item 1. [B] test item 2.
```

The current regex matches:

[A] test item 1. [B] test item 2.

In 1 string instead of 2 matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to have non-greedy behaviour:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]\](.*?)\. {1}
```

Note the question mark (`?`). It says that the expression coming right before it should match as little as possible to fullfil the expression. Basically, it makes it stop before the *first* dot and not the *last* one.

[Proof](http://regexr.com?322ff)

Comment: Instead of lazy dot .*? it's better to use a negating character class [^.]+ This matches anything except a dot.